# How to create custom validation within custom model field type?

Tags: python, django, validation, custom-fields

I am trying to make a school management system where super users who can add new students (and teachers later on) on the database have to also enter the student's courses. However, I want to use validation for different purposes:

1. Students need to take at least and a maximum of 1 option from the English and Math field (which does not need any further validation if left as it is)
2. Students need to take at least 1 science and a maximum of 2 --> Needs validation to ensure courses are not taken twice.
3. Students can pick any 3 courses from Science, Art, and Society, but cannot take the same courses twice.

I apologize if this question is silly or for any errors in the code as I started learning django and html 3 days ago to complete a school project. I read the django documentation in hopes for an answer but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

    class English(models.TextChoices):
        LANGLIT = 'LL', _('Language and literature')
        LIT = 'L', _('Literature')

    english = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=English.choices, default=English.LANGLIT)

    class Math(models.TextChoices):
        AA = 'AA', _('Analysis & Approaches')
        AI = 'AI', _('Analysis & Interpretation')

    math = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Math.choices, default=Math.AA)

    class Language(models.TextChoices):
        FRENCH = 'F', _('French')
        SPANISH = 'S', _('Spanish')
        ARABIC = 'A', _('Arabic')
        MANDARIN = 'M', _('Mandarin')

    language = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Math.choices, default=Language.FRENCH)

    class Science(models.TextChoices):
    BIOLOGY = 'BIO', _('Biology')
    CHEMISTRY = 'CHEM', _('Chemistry')
    PHYSICS = 'PHY', _('Physics')
    COMPUTERSCIENCE = 'CS', _('Computer Science')
    DESIGNTECHNOLOGY = 'DT', _('Design Technology')
    ESS = 'ESS', _('Environmental Systems and Societies')

    science = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=Science.choices, default=Science.BIOLOGY)

    class Society(models.TextChoices):
        MANAGEMENT = 'BM', _('Business Management')
        ECONOMICS = 'ECON', _('Economics')
        GEOGRAPHY = 'GEO', _('Geography')
        GLOBALPOLITICS = 'GP', _('Global Politics')
        HISTORY = 'HIS', _('History')
        PSYCHOLOGY = 'PSYCH', _('Psychology')

    class Art(models.TextChoices):
        VISUALARTS = 'VA', _('Visual Arts')
        MUSIC = 'MUS', _('Music'),
        FILM = 'FILM', _('Film')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ValidationError** and apply any logic you want

Example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_mail(value):
    if "@mail.com" in value:
        return value
    else:
        raise ValidationError("This field accepts mail only")

class MailModel(models.Model):
      mail = models.CharField(
                     max_length = 200,
                     validators =[validate_mail]
                     )
```